# Изменить и узнать регистр символа js

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте, есть символ

```
var symb = 'к';
```

**Вопрос 1:** Как узнать какой регистр (верхний/нижний)

---

**Вопрос 2:** Как повысить/понизить регистр символа (было 'к', стало 'К'). Я мог бы написать функцию с двумя массивами и заменой по индексу, но это будет не совсем корректно на мой взгляд. Можно ли осуществить это другим способом?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Узнать регистр символа**

```js
console.log('к' == 'к'.toUpperCase() ? 'Прописная' : 'Строчная');
console.log('K' == 'K'.toUpperCase() ? 'Прописная' : 'Строчная');
```

**Преобразование строк в верхний и нижний регистр соответственно**

```js
console.log('к'.toUpperCase()); // Преобразование строки в верхний регистр
console.log('K'.toLowerCase()); // Преобразование строки в нижний регистр
```

**Но возможна ситуация, когда символ — число.**

Тогда нужно будет делать дополнительную проверку.

```js
var char = 6; // или '5'

if (isNaN(char * 1)) {
  console.log(char == char.toUpperCase() ? 'Прописная' : 'Строчная');
} else {
  console.log('Число');
}
```

---

Для «нестандартных» локалей, типа турецкой смотрите в сторону методов [toLocaleLowerCase()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLocaleLowerCase) и [toLocaleUpperCase()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLocaleUpperCase)

Comment: `*1` можно не делать

Comment: @Grundy вы правы, в данной ситуации по видимому — да, `* 1` будет лишним. Но всё равно решение, которое привел нельзя считать идеальным, потому что вопрос, что делать в ситуации, когда символом может оказаться не только буква или число, но также и символы вроде `'+', '$', '.'` и т.д. Получается, что также нужно будет диапазон смотреть — входит ли символ в группу букв (русских ли, латинских ли, греческих ли и т.д.)... Будет ли для этого использоваться метод `charCodeAt()` (с которым тоже нюансы использования) или регулярное выражение... — зависит от задачи...

Answer (score 2):

```
toUpperCase / toLowerCase
```

Для смены регистра

```
var k = "f";
k.toUpperCase();
//"F"
k.toUpperCase() == k
//false
```

Comment: @pavel1787mego дополнил

Comment: Что значит работает с символом ? переведет в верхний\нижний регистр , все кроме символов

Comment: @pavel1787mego, в java script нет разницы между строкой и сиволом они обе равняются строке даже если 1 буква записанна, скобки так же не имеют значения.

Comment: @Horchynskyi, скорее между `'` и `"` нет разницы

Answer (score 0):

если по одному символу проверять то думаю подойдет и такое:

```js
var symb = 'к',
    symbUpper = 'K',
    test = 'L';
function whatRegist(char){
  if(char === char.toUpperCase()) return 'UpperRegist';
  else return 'LowerRegist';
}
console.log(whatRegist(symb));
console.log(whatRegist(symbUpper));
console.log(whatRegist(test));
```